# Getting DATETIME for rows inserted/Modified

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

am using SQL server 2005 , i have a requirement to get the Creation datetime of all the rows in a particular table, unfortunately the table do not have any "rowverion" or datetime column
( i know this is a major design flaw).

so , i was wondering if SQL server maintains datetime for each row inserts.

comments suggestions appreciated

Regards
Deepak

Answer (score 3):

No, SQL Server does not timestamp the rows automatically when they are created. As you suggested, for the future, you may want to create a new `date_created` column and set it default to `GETDATE()`:

```
ALTER TABLE       your_table  
  ADD CONSTRAINT  dc_your_table_date_created
  DEFAULT         GETDATE()
  FOR             date_created;
```

You may also use a trigger instead, if you prefer, as [@Vash suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351653/getting-datetime-for-rows-inserted-modified/3351685#3351685).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a bussines business, purpose you should add the column to table and create a triger  AFTER INSERT or UPDATE that set the sysdate to those rows. Or you can use the [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)